# Azure Application Gateway Combined Path Based and Redirect rules

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I want to modify my Azure Application Gwateway Path based and Redirect rules to exhibit the following behavior:

1. mygateway.com/test/* redirects to a website
2. mygateway.com/* forwards to a backend pool.

This is my current rule configuration but redirection is not occurring when I navigate to `/test/*`. Instead, all traffic is being routed to the `/*` path based rule.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the path based rule is being evaluated first since that is /*
everything is being sent there.

The way to fix it is to use the priority parameter to ensure that your redirect rule is evaluated first.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/rule?view=azure-cli-latest